# How to group FCM notifications in flutter

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies

How to group FCM notifications (having in one stack if there is more than one notification),
**I tried using the 'tag' key in my payload (as It was suggested in other answers)** but it makes that new notification replaces the last notification.

This what I am using for notification:

```
data: {
            'notification': {
                'title': notificationTitle,
                'body': notificationBody,
            },
            'priority': 'high',
            'data': {
                'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
                'id': '1',
                'status': 'done'
            },
            'to': userToken
           },
}
```